# Hamburger menu to the second row

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to create responsive menu. Everything works perfectly except for when I get to the 1024px I want to click on hamburger menu and align items to the center and each item will be in a separate row. My items won't display in second line under navbar after clicking on hamburger menu.

**Here's a code:**
https://codepen.io/S4UCY/pen/VwamrBb

**I want to create something similar to this:**
https://codepen.io/ladyareum/pen/eJVoPP

```js
const hamburger = document.getElementById('hamburger');
const menuUL = document.getElementById('menu-list');

hamburger.addEventListener('click',  () => {
  menuUL.classList.toggle('show');
});
```

```css
* GENERAL */
html, body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

/* * {
    outline:2px solid red;
} */

body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat',sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.group:before,
.group:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.group:after{
    clear: both;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

/* NAVBAR */
.navbar {
    border: none;
    font-size: 1.1428571428571428em;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: #cc9efd;
}

.navbar {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.navbar .logo-place{
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #fff;
}

.site-title a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

/* DROPDOWN-MENU */
.menu-list,.menu-list ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.menu-list ul {
    height:0;
    left:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
}

.menu-list li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

.menu-list li a {
    background-color:#cc9efd;
    color:#fff;
    display:block;
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:35px;
    padding:5px 20px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.menu-list li:hover > a {
    background:#fff;
    color:#cc9efd;
}

.menu-list li:hover ul.subs {
    height:auto;
    width:180px;
}

.menu-list ul li {
    opacity:0;
    width:100%;
}

.menu-list li:hover ul li {
    opacity:1;
}

.menu-list ul li a {
    background:#fff;
    color:#cc9efd;
    line-height:1px;
}

.menu-list li:hover ul li a {
    line-height:35px;
}

.menu-list li a:hover {
    background: #f2f4f5;
}

.menu-list li ul li a:hover {
    background: #f2f4f5;
}

/* HAMBURGER */
.hamburger {
    display: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.hamburger:focus {
    outline: none;
}

/* SOCIAL-ICONS-HEADER */
.header-right a{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 5px;

    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 35px;

    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 3px;
}

.header-right a:first-child{
    margin-left: 0;
}

.header-right .fa{
    margin-top: 3px;
}


/* MEDIA QUERIES */

/* HAMBURGER */
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .hamburger{
        position: absolute;
        display: inline-block;
        right:0;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }

    .menu-list {
        display: none;
    }

    .menu-list.show{
        display: block;
    }

    .show a{
        background: #000!important;

    }

    .header-right {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Lorem</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@200;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- HEADER, NAVBAR -->
    <header>
      <!-- NAVBAR -->
      <div class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="logo-place">
            <span class="site-title"><a href="index.html">LOREM</a></span>
          </div>
          <button class="hamburger" id="hamburger"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></button>
          <div class="menu">
            <ul class="menu-list" id="menu-list">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                    <ul class="subs">
                        <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Tools <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                    <ul class="subs">
                        <li><a href="#">First mode</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Second mode</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Back-up <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                  <ul class="subs">
                      <li><a href="#">1 month</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">1 year</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div id="second-menu-navi-header" class="header-right">

            <a id="tab-1-header" href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram instagram-logo-footer"></i></a>
            <a id="tab-2-header" href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube youtube-logo-footer"></i></a>
            <a id="tab-3-header" href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter twitter-logo-footer"></i></a>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/hamburger.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some code to `@media screen and (max-width: 1024px)`, like `.menu-list li:hover ul.subs`, `.menu`, and remove `position:absolute` from `.hamburger`. Hope this solve your problem.

```js
const hamburger = document.getElementById('hamburger');
const menuUL = document.getElementById('menu-list');

hamburger.addEventListener('click',  () => {
  menuUL.classList.toggle('show');
});
```

```css
* GENERAL */
html, body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

/* * {
    outline:2px solid red;
} */

body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat',sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.group:before,
.group:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.group:after{
    clear: both;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

/* NAVBAR */
.navbar {
    border: none;
    font-size: 1.1428571428571428em;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: #cc9efd;
}

.navbar {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.navbar .logo-place{
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #fff;
}

.site-title a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

/* DROPDOWN-MENU */
.menu-list,.menu-list ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.menu-list ul {
    height:0;
    left:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
}

.menu-list li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

.menu-list li a {
    background-color:#cc9efd;
    color:#fff;
    display:block;
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:35px;
    padding:5px 20px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.menu-list li:hover > a {
    background:#fff;
    color:#cc9efd;
}

.menu-list li:hover ul.subs {
    height:auto;
    width:180px;
}

.menu-list ul li {
    opacity:0;
    width:100%;
}

.menu-list li:hover ul li {
    opacity:1;
}

.menu-list ul li a {
    background:#fff;
    color:#cc9efd;
    line-height:1px;
}

.menu-list li:hover ul li a {
    line-height:35px;
}

.menu-list li a:hover {
    background: #f2f4f5;
}

.menu-list li ul li a:hover {
    background: #f2f4f5;
}

/* HAMBURGER */
.hamburger {
    display: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.hamburger:focus {
    outline: none;
}

/* SOCIAL-ICONS-HEADER */
.header-right a{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 5px;

    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 35px;

    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 3px;
}

.header-right a:first-child{
    margin-left: 0;
}

.header-right .fa{
    margin-top: 3px;
}


/* MEDIA QUERIES */

/* HAMBURGER */
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .hamburger{
/*      position: absolute; */
        display: inline-block;
        right:0;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }

    .menu {
        width:100%
    }
    
    .menu-list {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .menu-list li {
        float:none
    }
    
    .menu-list li:hover ul.subs {
        z-index:1;
        width:100%;
        position:unset;
    }
    
    .menu-list.show{
        display: block;
    }

    .show a{
        background: #000!important;

    }

    .header-right {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Lorem</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@200;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- HEADER, NAVBAR -->
    <header>
      <!-- NAVBAR -->
      <div class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="logo-place">
            <span class="site-title"><a href="index.html">LOREM</a></span>
          </div>
          <button class="hamburger" id="hamburger"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></button>
          <div class="menu">
            <ul class="menu-list" id="menu-list">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                    <ul class="subs">
                        <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Tools <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                    <ul class="subs">
                        <li><a href="#">First mode</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Second mode</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Back-up <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                  <ul class="subs">
                      <li><a href="#">1 month</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">1 year</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div id="second-menu-navi-header" class="header-right">

            <a id="tab-1-header" href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram instagram-logo-footer"></i></a>
            <a id="tab-2-header" href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube youtube-logo-footer"></i></a>
            <a id="tab-3-header" href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter twitter-logo-footer"></i></a>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/hamburger.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```